# Angular 4 and modules: Rangy

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, rangy

I'm new to Angular 4, I just created a simple app forking the Angular quickstart and now I'm trying to import [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy).

On `package.json` I now have the following dependencies:

```
"rangy": "^1.3.0",
"@types/rangy": "^0.0.27"
```

I expected to be able to simply do a

```
import {RangySelection} from 'rangy';
```

but that just gives me the error

```
TS2306: File '/projects/mylittleapp/node_modules/@types/rangy/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I understand that it has to do with SystemJS and how to import modules there, but I can't figure out how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TypeScript**

According to `@types/rangy` you have two options:

Option 1. `import 'rangy'`

- you get global variable 'rangy'
- doesn't work with `SystemJS`

Option 2. `import * as rangy from 'rangy'`

- you get local variable 'rangy' (or whatever you define)

You can't do `import rangy from 'rangy'` because `rangy` doesn't have default es6 export.

You can't do `import { RangySelection } from 'rangy'` because `rangy` is not es6 compatible module. Interface `RangySelection` will be available with both options of import.

**Angular (SystemJS)**

To get the module returned from server properly, you must tell `SystemJS` where it should look for it. This is done inside `System.config`:

Add line `'rangy': 'npm:rangy/lib/rangy-core.js',` to `map` element of config. Whole config from angular quickstart:

```
System.config({
  paths: {
    // paths serve as alias
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
  },
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
    // our app is within the app folder
    'app': 'app',

    // angular bundles
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

    // other libraries
    'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    'rangy': 'npm:rangy/lib/rangy-core.js',
  },
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  packages: {
    app: {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      meta: {
        './*.js': {
          loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
        }
      }
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How nice, it works! What about the Save & Restore module? How can I create a new RangySelection object? I tried to add the rangy-selectionsaverestore.js to System.js, without success...

Comment: You use `rangy.getSelection` or `rangy.createRange` to get respective instances. As for rangy modules - I really don't know how to properly load them. Also there are no typings for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me!

Comment: I'm going to ditch the Rangy module system and bring it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The type definitions for Rangy indicate that it has no exported modules. It only declares a variable called `rangy`. So you can use it like:

```
import "rangy";

rangy.getSelection();
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I only get a 404 and a SystemJS error...
Do I have to add Rangy to system.config.js? I've tried to do so under System.config.map: 
    
    'rangy': 'npm:rangy/lib/rangy-core.js' , 

but it didn't help either.

Comment: What url are you getting a 404 on? And looking at the rangy library, looks like it supports commonjs and AMD modules. Looks like the type definitions are not up to date.

Comment: If I change the systemjs.config.js as described, I get a `Error: (SystemJS) rangy is not defined`, otherwise the 404 is for http://localhost:3000/rangy.

Answer (score 0):

The rangy npm package does not deliver any typings. That means you have to utilize that yourself through defining a simple typing:

```
declare var rangy:any;
```

This makes rangy available in your code and you can just use it wherever you want.

With angular cli you can include the required .js file in the .angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-core.js"
  ]
```

Otherwise take the cdn hosting and ad it to the index.html.

Here is a Plunker example using the cdn version:

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QvNUCqhnaJJkYDoxMPd7?p=preview)