# Error using Rangy - methods are not working in Angular5

Tags: angular, textselection, rangy

[Angular 4 and modules: Rangy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251158/angular-4-and-modules-rangy)
I followed the instructions above to import rangy. I want to use TextRange's function [expand()](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) in Rangy's [documentation](https://github.com/timdown/rangy). However, I get the error Property 'expand' does not exist on type 'RangySelection'.

My code:

```
    import * as rangy from 'rangy'

    showSelectedText(){
      var selTxt = rangy.getSelection()*.expand()*;
      console.log('selTxt: '+selTxt);
}
```

On console.log(rangy), I get:

[image]

console.log(rangy.getSelection()) gives as output 
[image]

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(rangy)`?

Comment: I am updating my question to show what happens @JeffreyRoosendaal

Comment: add `"../node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-textrange.js"` in scripts array of your `.angular.cli.json`  and tell me what's the o/p

Comment: @Vikas I get the same error. For some reason rangy.expand() is not a function too.

Comment: Did you restart your app after modification?

Comment: Angular won't pick up the changes made to `.angular.cli.json` that's why you need to restart your application

Comment: @Vikas I did rerun my app still get an error saying rangy.expand is not a function.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @NikitaMarinosyan rangy still isn't working. My issue is open but I was able to implement most of the functions I needed. Its a little annoying but not impossible.

Comment: I found a workaround with importing it like this:                                           
```import * as rangy from 'rangy';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-core';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-textrange';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-serializer';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-highlighter';```                                                                    But I don't know how it works :D Also I created property inside a component: `private rangy = rangy as any`

Answer (score 1):

Something that worked for me in the past is importing one of the modules.
And importing the other modules if needed.

```
    import * as rangy from 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';
    import 'rangy/lib/rangy-highlighter'; //imports another module into rangy
    import 'rangy/lib/rangy-core.js'; //and another
    import 'rangy/lib/rangy-textrange';
    import 'rangy/lib/rangy-serializer';
```

Comment: It almost worked for me. import * as rangy from 'rangy';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-core';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-textrange';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-serializer';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-highlighter'; Also I created property inside a component: `private rangy = rangy as any`

Answer (score 1):

A Rangy selection only has an `expand()` method if the [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) is loaded. This is because this module is a fairly large bit of code and isn't loaded as part of Rangy's core. You just need to ensure that the module code is loaded, by whatever means you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the function is broken as console.log(Rangy.getSelection()) does not show expand() as an option.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in this thread:
https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/136

The issue is fixed in new version.
yet if you still have issue try using it this way:

```
let expandWord = rangy.getSelection();
expandWord.expand("word", {
   trim: true
});
```

Plus:
To avoid error message in angular2+. add its types as below.
try installing the types for Rangy:

> npm install --save @types/rangy

Afterwards edit the index.d.ts file and add expand function to the types. in RangySelection Interface.

```
interface RangySelection extends Selection {
    nativeSelection: Selection;
    isBackwards(): boolean;
    refresh(checkForChanges?: boolean): any;
    toHtml(): string;
    getAllRanges(): RangyRange[];
    getRangeAt(idx: number): RangyRange;
    getNativeTextRange(): any;
    setSingleRange(range: RangyRange): any;
    setRanges(ranges: RangyRange[]): any;
    getBookmark(containerNode: Node): any;
    moveToBookmark(bookmark: Object): any;
    saveRanges(): Object;
    restoreRanges(saved: Object): any;
    saveCharacterRanges(containerNode: Node, opts?: any): Object;
    restoreCharacterRanges(containerNode: Node, characterRanges: Object, opts?: any): any;
    detach(): any;
    inspect(): string;
    move(units: string, count: number, opts?: any): number;
    //This One
    expand(session, unit?, expandOptions?);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the module is loaded (as you can see in your `console.log()`), but the methods aren't working, try installing the types for Rangy:

`npm install --save @types/rangy`

---

If that still does not work, you can try:

`(rangy as any).getSelection().expand();`

---

Also, make sure `rangy.getSelection()` returns a rangy object (and not `undefined`), otherwise `expand()` will not be available.

Comment: I tried both the things but I still get an error TypeError:  rangy.getSelection(...).expand is not a function

Comment: But `console.log(rangy.getSelection())` does work? Maybe it's not a function because `getSelection()` returns `undefined` instead of a rangy object.

Comment: I put in my question what I get from rangy.getSelection() it does not return undefined

Comment: I see. But it doesn’t list `expand()` as a method either. Are you sure you can use those two together? Have you tried without Angular?

Comment: they use them together in their demo https://github.com/timdown/rangy/blob/master/demos/textrange.html. I have concluded that it's just broken. Do you know of a similar module?

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Too be honest, I don't really have an idea what rangy does, but maybe you can [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454152/cross-browser-selection-range-library):

Comment: A Rangy selection only has an `expand()` method if the [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) is loaded.