# Importing rangy in Angular 17 fails with 'crippled' object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, rangy

I am having issues in using [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) with an Angular 17 application. I am using the latest available version of rangy (1.3.1), on a newly created application using `ng new`, as follows:

(1) create a new Angular 17 app: `ng new rangy-repro`

(2) install [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) (latest version 1.3.1) and its types:

```bash
npm install rangy
npm install @types/rangy --save-dev --force
```

(3) import rangy in `app-component.ts`:

```
import * as rangy from 'rangy';
```

as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251158/angular-4-and-modules-rangy), and working up to recent time.

(4) in the `AppComponent` constructor, call `rangy.getSelection`:

```
let s = rangy.getSelection();
```

When I run the app, I get an error because `rangy` has no `getSelection` function defined (which BTW is the only function I need, yet it does not seem that there are alternatives to `rangy` here).

The same code and library version works fine in an Angular apps created with previous versions of Angular CLI (15 in my case), which did not yet have the standalone components option as the default, and so still use modules. There, the `getSelection` function is defined in the `rangy` object, together with other functions and properties. Here  instead I get only a few members, like `init`, `version`, etc., but not `getSelection`. I also get a `default` property.

Of course, Angular always reminds me that rangy is not ESM, but this did not affect its functionality, at least in previous versions. When I compile, now I still get a warning:

```
 [WARNING] Module 'rangy' used by 'src/app/app.component.ts' is not ESM
  CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
  For more information see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

But then I also get a crippled version of the `rangy` object. AFAIK, this may point to some tree-shaking related issue.

I have tried to directly import rangy JS like:

```
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-core.js';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-textrange';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-serializer';
```

or even just `import { getSelection } from 'rangy';`, or to import the JS files directly in `angular.json` under scripts:

```json
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-core.js",
  "node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-textrange.js",
  "node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-serializer.js",
  "node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js",
  "node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier.js",
  "node_modules/rangy/lib/rangy-highlighter.js"
]
```

Yet, nothing changes, and at any rate if tree-shaking is the culprit it would be working the same even in this case.

If I generate a non-standalone app, using `ng new rangy-repro --standalone false`, and then add the `rangy` package and import and use it as described above, I get the same issue; so at least this does not seem to be related to standalone in itself, but rather to other build issues. If tree shaking is the culprit, how can I disable it for `rangy`? Or can you suggest any other workaround to use `rangy` in an Angular 17 application?